# facing issue while using mysql using xammp

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

i am learning MySql and facing issue while entering the following commands

C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1

Enter password:

(password left blank since I didn't saved any password)

**ERROR 1045 (28000):[image]** Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found. Library path is 'caching_sha2_password.dll'

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: mysql version  8.0